# Elementary embedding between transitive sets

Tags: logic, set-theory, model-theory

I was originally going to ask whether this statement has consistency strength over $\mathsf{ZFC}$: there exist transitive sets $M,N$ with $N\subseteq M$ and a nontrivial elementary embedding $j:M\rightarrow N$ (moves some ordinal). Then I realized Ehrenfeucht-Fraisse game can probably be used to show the existence of nontrivial $j:\kappa\rightarrow\kappa$ for any cardinal $\kappa$. So my question is what if we require $M$ to satisfy some basic set theory, like pairing+union? What's the "strongest" theory $T$ for which such a pair satisfying $T$ is relatively consistent with (or provably exists in) $\mathsf{ZFC}$?

As a first attempt, if $j:\kappa\rightarrow\kappa$ is an elementary embedding, and $M$ is the closure of $\kappa$ under pairing and union, does $j$ extend to an elementary $j^+:M\rightarrow M$?

Remark: Since ordinals are definable in any transitive set (an ordinal is a transitive set of transitive sets), $j$ must restrict to an elementary embedding of $M\cap\mathrm{Ord}$ into $N\cap\mathrm{Ord}$, so $M\cap\mathrm{Ord}\subseteq N\cap\mathrm{Ord}$. Since I also assume $N\subseteq M$, we have $M\cap\mathrm{Ord}=N\cap\mathrm{Ord}$. Without requiring $N\subseteq M$ there are easy examples in $\mathsf{ZFC}$. It seems the exact consistency strength of $j:M\rightarrow M$ where $M\models\mathsf{ZFC}$ is [known](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/319231/consistency-strength-of-jl-%CE%B4%E2%86%92l-%CE%B4-for-some-%CE%B4), but my question is more about how much set theory can we make $M$ satisfy if working in $\mathsf{ZFC}$.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote on this question, it's perfectly reasonable; maybe the downvoter isn't familiar with the (completely standard) terminology used here. As you expect, as long as $\kappa$ is an (uncountable!) cardinal, there is a nontrivial elementary embedding from $\kappa$ to itself; indeed, any "sufficiently closed" ordinal $>\omega$ will have this property.

Comment: This is an excellent question! It seems related to questions about when elementary embeddings $M\to M$ can be extended to elementary embeddings $L(M)\to L(M)$ (or perhaps from $V_\alpha\to V_\alpha$ to $V_{\alpha+1}\to V_{\alpha+1}$). I believe in the I0--I3 large cardinal context, full elementarity at the lower level gives you something like $\Delta_0$-elementarity of the extension, but I'm not sure how relevant that is for the weak theories you are considering.